# Python: Can you add two list element by element?

Tags: python, list

Can you add two lists element by element with out iterating through it as below? This works, but eh. I miss matlab.

```
list1 = [3, 7, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

for x in range(0, len(list1)): 
   list1[x] = list1[x] + list2[x]

print (list1)

Output :
[7, 12, 9]
```

Comment: "I miss matlab." Use numpy then... (and btw all methods will iterate over your lists, the question is whether it is hidden under the hood or not...)

Comment: Yes, but some methods are optimized because they are performed a lot.That is more of what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` the lists together, and `sum` the pairs

```
list(map(sum, zip(list1, list2)))
```

EDIT:

I did some basic testing, and the overwhelming winners were the list comprehension if the input data starts as lists, and `numpy` if you can have it as arrays before your operation

```
def test1(list1, list2):
  l=[]
  for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    l.append(list1[x] + list2[x])
  return l    

def test2(list1, list2):
  return list(map(sum, zip(list1, list2)))

def test3(list1, list2):
  return [x+y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

import numpy as np

def test4(list1, list2):
  return np.array(list1) + np.array(list2)

def test5(list1, list2):
  return list1 + list2

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('test1(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = list(range(100)); list2 = list(range(100))', globals=globals()))
print(timeit('test2(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = list(range(100)); list2 = list(range(100))', globals=globals()))
print(timeit('test3(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = list(range(100)); list2 = list(range(100))', globals=globals()))
print(timeit('test4(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = list(range(100)); list2 = list(range(100))', globals=globals()))
print(timeit('test4(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = np.array(list(range(100))); list2 = np.array(list(range(100)))', globals=globals()))
print(timeit('test5(list1, list2)', setup='list1 = np.array(list(range(100))); list2 = np.array(list(range(100)))', globals=globals()))
```

Gives me

```
15.42712744511664 # append
17.329718918073922 # my solution above
7.0252319818828255 # list comprehension
16.53089915495366 # numpy with list inputs
1.430903600063175 # numpy with array inputs that are double checked
0.6451617309357971 # numpy assuming array inputs
```

These are the times in seconds to execute the operation 1000000 times.

Numpy is surprisingly slow when forced to do `np.array(list)` every time.

Try it yourself at [this repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/HumongousFrigidGlobefish)

Comment: Is that going to be more efficient then the for loop?

Comment: The most efficient way as I think is using numpy. See Fatih's answer.

Comment: @zippo I threw together a little time trial to see what's actually fastest.

Comment: Thats awesome! Really answered my question!

Answer (score 3):

Don't miss Matlab at all :) The numpy arrays are your typical Matlab arrays:

```
arr1 = np.array([3, 7, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
arr1 + arr2
```

gives you what you want.

If you want to stick with lists, you can do this:

```
list1 = [3, 7, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
[sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

---

After the performance comments, especially Patrick's comparison, I did a comparison myself, and verified that numpy is actually the fastest among the current solutions posted. However, there is another solution which beats numpy! Let's see:

```
# Numpy:
timeit arr1 + arr2 # 1.67 µs per loop
# List comprehension:
timeit [sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)] # 2.59 µs per loop
timeit [(x+y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)] # 1.72 µs per loop
# Map and Reduce-based (note that reduce is really overkill, I did it just for fun):
timeit map(sum, zip(list1, list2)) # 2.58 µs per loop
timeit map(lambda a, b: a + b , list1, list2) # 2.11 µs per loop
timeit [reduce((lambda x,y: x+y), e) for e in zip(list1,list2)] # 4.05 µs per loop
# And the winner:
from operator import add
timeit map(add, list1, list2) # 1.57 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want matlab-like behavior, you should use `numpy`

```
In [5]: list1 = [3, 7, 3]

In [6]: list2 = [4, 5, 6]

In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: np.array(list1) + np.array(list2)
Out[8]: array([ 7, 12,  9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension over both the lists

```
list1 = [3, 7, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [(x+y) for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[7, 12, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **lambda** and a **map**:

```
>>> list1 = [3, 7, 3]
>>> list2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list(map(lambda a, b: a + b , list1, list2))
[7, 12, 9]
```